# HTML4 (or anything pre-HTML5) Offline Storage - What/How?

Tags: html

I know HTML5 has offline storage capabilities.  What were others doing for offline storage capabilities in the pre-HTML5 days?

Answer (score 2):

For small amounts of data, cookies & response caching.
For large amounts of data, Flash (or similar plugin tech) to save files.
HTML and JS deliberately avoid having the ability to explicitly modify the client's file-system in any way, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plug-ins like Flash, Silverlight, Google Gears to store data. You can also use cookies or browser specific features (like IE userdata). If you don't want to build your own adapter to switch between all these solutions, you can use [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557).

Answer (score 0):

You could have built/used something like YUI's local storage library.

- YUI3 - http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/storage-lite
- YUI2 - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/

It's a combination of different ways like SWF storage, HTML5 and older browser specific APIs.